# Cualquier comando que escribo me da error

Tags: c++, vscode

Estoy intentando poner a funcionar vcpkg para poder empezar a programar en visual studio code, pero siempre que meto el comando en la consola de Windows, me da error:

```
$ .\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
bash: .vcpkgbootstrap-vcpkg.bat: command not found
```

¿Alguien me puede decir qué estoy haciendo mal, u otra forma de escribir C++ en Visual studio code sin tener que instalar esto? También he instalado la versión más reciente de g++ con mingw y la última versión de Git, así que no sé dónde puede estar el problema.

El mensaje de error que me aparece en visual studio cada vez que intento inicializar el código es:

> Se han detectado errores de #include. Actualice el valor de includePath. El subrayado ondulado está deshabilitado para esta unidad de traducción (C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\cosa de prueba\probar.cpp).

Comment: solo para aclarar ¿clonaste el proyecto con git?

Comment: Sí, también me dio error al principio pero al final lo conseguí. Ahora mismo estoy trasteando con los compiladores, aunque sigo sin avanzar (nada más publicar el comentario he conseguido que funcione. Gracias de todos modos).

Comment: No lo estas colocando  en la cosola de windows, lo estas colocando en bash, probablemente el que traiga git. Si lo vas a correr desde bash, tiene que ser el archivo `.sh`. Yo te recomendaria hacerlo con el `.bat` desde la verdadera terminal de windows. Dale a la tecla de windows y escribe cmd, te saldra ahi.